# Is there a way to prevent outside access to container memory

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualization

So i'm playing around the idea of application containers and os containers and I was wondering if it is possible to prevent code to access the container memory from the outside (from the machine that's running the container).

I understand that application container prevents the process inside the container to access other processes in the system (and interact with them?), but what if a container is used to prevent users to mess with the process, is it even possible?

For example if I run a game in the container, can I bring it to a state that people can't use hacks on the game process?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No

Unless you put it into something you control. Easiest way is when you physically control computer where it is running, but that's not what you want. Another way is to put it in some tamper resistant computer, but these are mostly small and weak (eg. simcards and secure storage for private keys). 
And even those are not 100% secure.

Comment: If I say I have access to the computer physically is there a way to prevent it?

Or atleast deny the access for some time?

Comment: Then you can start. But you must be better than attacker (or use better tools).

Comment: You probubly whould ask new question (and other, more knowlegefull people will answer). And put there what you want to allow other people to do with your computer. If nothing then its cafe, just dont connect it to anything ;)

Comment: So the idea that I'm after is the ability to create a sterile environment for games to run, I understand it obviously won't be bullet proof on someone physical computer but in a scenario for example there is a tournament and the computers supply by the orgranizers.

Or for example release some kind of verification code or something similar right before the game begins.

Even maybe take an exe and modify it's binary for  many different versions (kinda obfuscation)  so hacks already built in and using hard coded memory addresses won't work for example.

Comment: Yeah. and remove/cover with tape all unneeded inputs (usb etc. don't allow players to use their own mouse and disqualify for disconnecting anything from computer).